# Can I find out who filed a DMCA request with AdSense against my genuine website?

Tags: google-adsense, content, google-adsense-policies, dmca

So basically AdSense reported today that two of my pages have been DMCA and ads for those two pages are disabled.

Now I think my pages are genuine, I wrote the text my self without plagiarism: it's a software review where I provide the link to the original software house.

Is there any way to know who filed the DMCA request? If it's a my competitor I would fill the counter DMCA request.

Comment: And do you use your own images? since it's normally videos or images that trigger DCMA, not text content unless it's duplicated or reworded using a spinner.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should be able to use [Lumen](https://lumendatabase.org/) (formerly Chilling Effects) to look up the DMCA complaint against your site and see who filed it.

> If it's a my competitor I would fill the counter DMCA request.

I wouldn't. Filing a false request can have some negative repercussions for you.

Comment: what? someone did a false DMCA request and I cannot counter notice it?

Comment: anyway I tried to search my website in Lumen and nothing appears, what can I look for?

Comment: 1. Are you sure that this was a full DMCA takedown and not just the threat of one to the ISP? Most ISPs will preemptively take content down in response to even a threat. 2. Lumen is not real time, it can take a few weeks for complaints to show.